# removing 99999 values from cvs in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am working with a large data set (over 400 columns and 200000 rows) and for some values that wasn't recorded, there is a '-9999.99' value in that slot. How do I remove these values from my imported data through python? I imported using a csv file in pandas. I don't want to remove the whole column, just any data box that has the -9999.99 value since it is meaningless and is messing up my mean and standard deviation values. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After loading data in a DataFrame, replace is one option:

```
df.replace(-9999.99, '', inplace=True)
```

or

```
df.replace(-9999.99, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Comment: In this case, I would recommend adding the `inplace=True` parameter, i.e. remove the `df =` at the start.